# some bindings not updating in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube-api

I'm consuming data from the youtube api, and displaying it with ng-repeat.

Strangely, some of my {{bindings}} are updating when the model changes, while some are not always.

This is my template:

```
<div class="videosearch">
    <input class="videosearchbox" type="text" ng-model="videosearch.search" />
    <div class="videosearchelement" ng-repeat="video in videosearch.videos track by $index" ng-click="videosearch.selectVideo(video.id.videoId)">
        <div class="videosearchtitle">
            {{video.snippet.title}}
        </div>
        <img class="videosearchthumb" ng-src="{{video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

now, when I do a search (reasigns the videosearch.videos property to a new array) the image tags *always* update, while the title tags *sometimes* update, I'm not sure what triggers it, but once they have stopped updating, they will not update again untill I refresh the page, but the images always update perfectly.

note that my callback is inside of a digest cycle, so it is not a case of $apply being necessary

Thanks,
Nico

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plunker reproducing this issue?

Comment: @Paritosh I can try, I was hoping someone would see something obvious, I'll look into making a sample, in the mean time the current link is [link](http://nicom1.github.io/assorted/tests/youtube), which I know won't give all the sources cuz its angular, but you can see the app.js, and in my question I show the videosearch part that renders out the data, may help